# Unexpected value 'PdfmakeModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, node-modules

I am trying to use [ng-pdf-make](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdf-make) in my angular application. Below is my `app.module.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PdfmakeModule } from 'ng-pdf-make';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    PdfmakeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As soon as i import the `ng-pdf-make` into my module am getting below error in the console

`Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'PdfmakeModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

`ng-pdf-make` version `0.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Don't include full module, just add only service PdfmakeService to providers and add

**import {PdfmakeService} from 'ng-pdf-make/pdfmake/pdfmake.service';**

to component.